# discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions when I try to send message

Tags: python, discord

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=20)
async def __random_time_money():
    value = random.randint(4, 15)
    time.sleep(value)
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        ch = guild.get_channel(base.execute("""SELECT main_channel FROM guild_name WHERE guild_id = {}""".format(guild.id)).fetchone()[0])
        print(ch)
        await ch.send("hi")
```

When I start this code terminal send:
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

P.S. Sorry for my bad english

I surf internet around 2 hours and not find any information about that.

Comment: Are you using `discord.py`? You might want to add the tag for it. I don't use it myself though. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 0):

Your bot can't send messages in the channel you're trying to send it.

Please, make sure your bot has correct permissions to send messages in a desired channel (Which ID is in your database)

Comment: Спасибо! Не допёр сначала) поставил блок try, и всё заработало